# How to prevent the "Fullcalendar" showing the date and time lesser than now

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have fullcalendar with "dayGridMonth" and "timeGridDay" views. I want to show dates from the "now" moment.

It's the source code of my calendar widget below:

```
    let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, bootstrap, interaction],
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
    showNonCurrentDates: false,
    fixedWeekCount: false,
    header: {
        right: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        left: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridDay'
    },
    eventTimeFormat: {
        hour: '2-digit', //2-digit, numeric
        minute: '2-digit', //2-digit, numeric
        hour12: false //true, false
    },
    views: {
        timeGridDay: {
            nowIndicator: true,
            selectable: true,
            allDaySlot: false,
            slotLabelFormat: {
                hour: '2-digit',
                minute: '2-digit',
                hour12: false //true, false
            }
        },
    },
    validRange: {
        start: moment.now()
    },
    events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json',
    selectOverlap: false,
        });


    calendar.render();
});
```

[image: How can I achieve it?]
[image]

Comment: You can't prevent those days being displayed on the screen, but you can disable them and prevent events from being shown within them. There's an example here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/validRange

Comment: @ADyson as you can see, I've already done it. But anyway there is one more problem. It doesn't work for a `timeGridDay` view. My purpose is to prevent select/click  datetime lesser than 'now'(in other words hide corresponding cells or just make them inactive). With `validRange` option I still can select time-cells in `timeGridDay`

Comment: " as you can see, I've already done it"...sorry but then why did you ask a question about it? This site is for posting questions/problems with code, not showcasing your solutions. It would have been better to ask specifically about the timeGridDay issue in the first place, if that was what was really bothering you. I admit I didn't look so closely at your code to see you'd already implemented something (because normally the reason for posting would be because you are having trouble with implementing!)

Comment: @ADyson because my main question is "How to prevent **showing** the date and time...". And as I said above `validRange` does not affect the time-cells in `timeGridDay` view

Comment: "validRange does not affect the time-cells in timeGridDay view"...yes but you didn't mention that in the question. Like I said, if you have a specific issue, then mention it, don't just ask a more general question. Anyway I think that's not something which is solvable, it seems that validRange only accepts dates. You probably need to make a feature request to fullCalendar if you want that fixing. There are other ways you can use as workarounds to constrain the display/selection of dates using various of the other available callbacks in the API.

Comment: And as I already said, you can't hide the specific dates. Hence why I moved onto the disabling of them instead. In the timegridDay view you could potentially set "minTime" dynamically based on the current time, but you can't do anything to change the month view. Again you could make a feature request, if you think it's useful.